# Active menu item does not work on multi language (/?lang=nl)

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out how to get the *url.replace* right. The active class is added like intended. But when I go to the other language the function doesn't seem to work.

I believe this is because of the *url.replace* but have not yet found how to fix this for all urls.

**This works on:** example.com/page/ 
**Does not work on:** example.com/page/?lang=nl

```js
$(function() {
  var url = window.location.pathname,
      urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");
  $('#nav a.menu-item-text').each(function() {
    if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).parent().previoussibling().find('a').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

English HTML

```html
<nav id="nav" class="ct-div-block nav-container">

  <div id="div_block-13-14" class="ct-div-block menu-item-container">
    <a id="text_block-14-14" class="ct-link-text menu-item-text" 
       href="https://example.com/properties/">Properties</a>
    <div id="div_block-16-14" class="ct-div-block border-animation"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div_block-17-14" class="ct-div-block menu-item-container">
    <a id="text_block-18-14" class="ct-link-text menu-item-text" 
       href="https://example.com/districts-ibiza/">Districts</a>
    <div id="div_block-19-14" class="ct-div-block border-animation"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div_block-26-14" class="ct-div-block menu-item-container">
    <a id="text_block-27-14" class="ct-link-text menu-item-text active" 
       href="https://example.com/about-us/">About us</a>
    <div id="div_block-28-14" class="ct-div-block border-animation"></div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Dutch HTML

```html
<nav id="nav" class="ct-div-block nav-container">

  <div id="div_block-13-14" class="ct-div-block menu-item-container">
    <a id="text_block-14-14" class="ct-link-text menu-item-text" 
       href="https://example.com/properties/?lang=nl">Properties</a>
    <div id="div_block-16-14" class="ct-div-block border-animation"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div_block-17-14" class="ct-div-block menu-item-container">
    <a id="text_block-18-14" class="ct-link-text menu-item-text"
       href="https://example.com/districts-ibiza/?lang=nl">Districts</a>
    <div id="div_block-19-14" class="ct-div-block border-animation"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div_block-26-14" class="ct-div-block menu-item-container">
    <a id="text_block-27-14" class="ct-link-text menu-item-text" 
       href="https://example.com/about-us/?lang=nl">About us</a>
    <div id="div_block-28-14" class="ct-div-block border-animation"></div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: When you go to the other language, does your .menu-item-text href also change for that other language?

Comment: The CSS stays the same. The page does change to the other language: domain.com/page/ -> domain.com/pagina/?lang=nl


— edit… URL stays the same. Only the ?lang=nl gets added

Comment: Can you provide an HTML sample of your `#nav` on your "base" page and the equivalent HTML on your "lang=" page?

Comment: Right, so back to my original question... (now I recall why I asked...) you're checking `window.location.pathname` vs href **which includes search** (?lang=nl).  So your lang page url is the same as non-lang page's url when you use `window.location.pathname` *but* the href is not the same - so your lang href's do not end in `example.com/page`.

Comment: Thank you! Removed the + "$" part. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is that the `<a href=` for the lang site includes `?lang=nl` and is compared with `window.location.pathname` which does not include this:

```
example.com/page -> window.location.pathname -> example.com/page
example.com/page?lang=nl -> window.location.pathname -> example.com/page
```

One option would be to convert them to javascript URL entities and compare, alternatively a small tweak to the regex will suffice

```
var urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "(/\?.*)$");
```

Here's a snippet showing all matches (for demonstrating/testing, eg include with/without ending "/").

```js
function setMenu(url) {
  var urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "(/\?.*)$");
  $('#nav a.menu-item-text').each(function() {
    if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      // remove this in the example to show all matches
      //$(this).parent().previoussibling().find('a').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
}

// pass test for window.location.pathname
setMenu("example.com/districts-ibiza/")
```

```css
.active { background-color: black; color: white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav" class="ct-div-block nav-container">

  <div id="div_block-13-14" class="ct-div-block menu-item-container">
    <a id="text_block-14-14" class="ct-link-text menu-item-text" 
       href="https://example.com/properties/">Properties</a>
    <div id="div_block-16-14" class="ct-div-block border-animation"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div_block-17-14" class="ct-div-block menu-item-container">
    <a id="text_block-18-14" class="ct-link-text menu-item-text" 
       href="https://example.com/districts-ibiza/">Districts</a>
    <div id="div_block-19-14" class="ct-div-block border-animation"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div_block-17-14" class="ct-div-block menu-item-container">
    <a id="text_block-18-14" class="ct-link-text menu-item-text" 
       href="https://example.com/districts-ibiza">Districts (no end slash)</a>
    <div id="div_block-19-14" class="ct-div-block border-animation"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div_block-26-14" class="ct-div-block menu-item-container">
    <a id="text_block-27-14" class="ct-link-text menu-item-text" 
       href="https://example.com/about-us/">About us</a>
    <div id="div_block-28-14" class="ct-div-block border-animation"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div_block-13-14" class="ct-div-block menu-item-container">
    <a id="text_block-14-14" class="ct-link-text menu-item-text" 
       href="https://example.com/properties/?lang=nl">Properties</a>
    <div id="div_block-16-14" class="ct-div-block border-animation"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div_block-17-14" class="ct-div-block menu-item-container">
    <a id="text_block-18-14" class="ct-link-text menu-item-text"
       href="https://example.com/districts-ibiza/?lang=nl">Districts</a>
    <div id="div_block-19-14" class="ct-div-block border-animation"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div_block-26-14" class="ct-div-block menu-item-container">
    <a id="text_block-27-14" class="ct-link-text menu-item-text" 
       href="https://example.com/about-us/?lang=nl">About us</a>
    <div id="div_block-28-14" class="ct-div-block border-animation"></div>
  </div>

</nav>
```